# Что лучше использовать: структуры или классы?

Tags: c++, классы, структуры

Насколько я знаю, классы более функциональны нежели структуры, однако программисты рекомендуют отдавать предпочтение структурам, когда не требуется использование функций в объекте.

Возможно ли их игнорировать последние или есть ситуации, когда без структур не обойтись?

Answer (score 5):

В С++ **всё** отличие классов от структур - в том, что в классе все поля, члены и классы-родители по умолчанию `private`, а в структуре - `public`.

Никаких других отличий нет.

```
struct A { int x, y; };
```

эквивалентно

```
class A { public: int x, y; };
```

а

```
class A { int x, y; };
```

эквивалентно

```
struct A { private: int x, y; };
```

Comment: Т.е,я правильно понимаю: они также имеют конструкторы, деструкторы, могут иметь наследников и т.п.?

Comment: Естественно. Указанное отличие - единственное. Другое дело - *стиль* кодирования, когда `struct` используют не с точки зрения функциональных возможностей, а, например, для подчеркивания того, что у этого типа есть только данные. Просто соглашение - такое же, как, скажем, типы писать с большой буквы, а переменные - с маленькой...

Comment: @ReturnNullprt если быть еще более точным, то и структуры и классы - это классы. Просто одни  "class defined with the class-key struct", а другие "class defined with the class-key class". К слову, в этой же тележке и `union`.

Comment: MSVC вообще структуры как классы с пабликом компилирует. И в ошибках нагло пишет "class X have..."

Comment: Есть еще отличия в наследовании спецификаторов.